# Why does a dynamic TabControl seem to be unable to switch between the tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

I'm using a dynamic TabControl in a page:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="DynamicTabControl"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TabsCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TabView}}}"
                SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                <DockPanel Width="30">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <local:TabItem/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

```
        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabsCollection {get;set;}
        private TabItem _tabAdd;

        #region Initialization
        public TabView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TabsCollection = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
            TabsCollection.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Tab 1"});

            // add a tabItem with + in header 
            _tabAdd = new TabItem
            {
                Header = "+"
            };

            TabsCollection.Add(_tabAdd);

            DynamicTabControl.DataContext = TabsCollection;
            DynamicTabControl.SelectedIndex=0;
        }
        #endregion

        private TabItem AddSubsequentTabItem()
        {
            int count = TabsCollection.Count;
            TabItem tab = new TabItem();
            
            tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
            tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);

            TabsCollection.Insert(count - 1, tab);
            return tab;
        }

        private void tabDynamic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem tab = DynamicTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
            if (tab == null) return;

            if (tab.Equals(_tabAdd))
            {
                // clear tab control binding
                DynamicTabControl.DataContext = null;

                TabItem newTab = this.AddSubsequentTabItem();

                // bind tab control
                DynamicTabControl.DataContext = TabsCollection;

                // select newly added tab item
                DynamicTabControl.SelectedItem = newTab;
            }
            else
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => DynamicTabControl.SelectedIndex = DynamicTabControl.SelectedIndex));
        }
```

But, I'm unable to get the tab control to switch between my TabItems.

I'm using an amalgamation of the dynamic tab control from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF , with modifications to create the GUI objects from within xaml.

My title pretty much says it all: Why is my TabControl not switching tabs? Even besides fixing the problem, I'd like to know if subscribing a method to the "selectionChanged" event unsubscribes the native tab switching.

[Here is the barebones example project of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iY9UCCHx3Wi4NaPwuCfzqEv4d-jPxNRN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I guess it is switching, but you only see the same default item, which makes it appear like nothing is happening. The ContentTemplate is useless, because you are adding TabItem controls directly (you are not working on data models). Of each TabItem, you rather have to set the TabItem.Content property to the individual content.

Comment: ItemTemplate seems also quite redundant here. Header is already set in code-behind. WPF will create a TextBlock implicitly to render the Header text. If you want true dynamic controls, then you should switch to work on data models and let controls like TabItem be generated automatically according to the defined ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate. Not all tutorials are good tutorials, obviously.

Comment: @BionicCode By "data models", do you mean MVVM?

Comment: No. MVVM is more than just using data models. You should create data model classes that you add to a collection which binds to the TabControl. Then define the ItemTemplate to describe the tab header and the ControlTemplate to describe the actual page content (both based on the data models). the TabControl will then create and initialize the TabItem container based on the templates. This is the preferred way. Although possible, you would always avoid creating UI elements like ListBoxItem, TreeViewItem or TabItem explicitly. This significantly simplifies your code and data handling.